# Output after git exited

Tags: bash, git

I run a simple script

```
#!/bin/bash
git fetch --all 2> stderr.txt
echo "Errorcode $?"
cat -n stderr.txt
echo Sleeping
sleep 1
cat -n stderr.txt
```

The strange point is the output

```
Fetching origin
Errorcode 1
     1  fatal: Couldn't find remote ref HEAD
     2  error: Could not fetch origin
Sleeping
     1  fatal: Couldn't find remote ref HEAD
     2  error: Could not fetch origin
     3  fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

And how can I *flush* the output and still be able to access the errorcode?

I tried it with `stdbuf -o0 -e0`, but without luck.

The flushing works with `tee`, but then the errorcode is lost.
`git fetch --all 2>&1 | tee stderr.txt > /dev/null`

Remarks:
- The error in this scenario is expected.
- The problem also occurs without the redirection of stderr.
- I used `git version 2.11.0`.

Comment: Are you only wanting "Errorcode NN" to show, and/or what is the desired output?

Comment: @l'L'l That I get the complete output in stderr.txt before I output it, but without a `sleep 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that internally, Git has forked off a separate process to do the fetching.  That separate process has told the parent Git that the fetch cannot succeed, before that separate process finishes writing its stderr, and the parent Git exits too soon.

You *cannot* fix this without modifying the Git source (which is freely available, so you *can* fix it, it's just not trivial).  You *can* work around it, though, e.g.:

```
if ! git fetch --all 2> stderr.txt; then
    failure=$?
    sleep 0.5 # or however long you think is appropriate
    ... do something with stderr.txt
    ... use the saved failure code in $? ...
else
    # the git fetch worked; $? is 0; no need to sleep
    ...
fi
```

The pipe trick is also useful but you'll need a shell with a feature like bash's `$PIPESTATUS` array.  Note that the pipe trick works because `tee` waits for all the writers of the pipe, and by running:

```
any-command-here 2>&1 | tee ...
```

you get your shell to wait for `tee`, which is waiting for not only the command itself, but also for anything the command spawned that could write to `tee`.

Comment: Thanks the `$PIPESTATUS` was the missing piece for me